# django render shortcut cannot find template

Tags: django, templates, render

thanks for anyone's help. My django cannot find the template file

```
Template loader Error:
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/rmdemo/rib.html (File      does not exist)
/home/shepherd/artekcloud/media/rmdemo/nodegraph/templates/rmdemo/rib.html (File does not exist)
/home/shepherd/artekcloud/media/rmdemo/rmdemo/templates/rmdemo/rib.html (File does not exist)
/home/shepherd/artekcloud/media/rmdemo/minikatana/templates/rmdemo/rib.html (File does not exist)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/rmdemo/rib.html (File does not exist)
```

And here is the traceback

```
Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response 115.  response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py" in render  53.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs),
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string 170.         t = get_template(template_name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py" in get_template  146.     template, origin = find_template(template_name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py" in find_template 139.     raise TemplateDoesNotExist(name)

Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist at /rmdemo/rib/
Exception Value: rmdemo/rib.html
```

I am using render shortcut to render the template

```
return render(request,'rmdemo/rib.html', {'loggedin': loggedin})
```

Any idea about how this happens? Why django looks into media folder instead of template folder inside the application folder?

I am pretty sure that the template file is under the app folder.

Comment: Please, add the values of your `TEMPLATE_DIRS` and `TEMPLATE_LOADERS` settings (from your `settings.py` file) to your post. This should make things much more clear.

Comment: And show where exactly the template actually is.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project settings.py & add this command on templates

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
```

and make sure import os